# Compiler Error java.Lang.Error file not found exception

Tags: java

Hey guys I'm getting an Java.Lang.Error (File not found exception) while trying to compile a .Java (its a class) File.
Here is the error i hope you can Help me

Errormessage:

```
An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_102). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
java.lang.Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\lib\tzdb.dat (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(ZoneInfoFile.java:261)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.<clinit>(ZoneInfoFile.java:251)
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getTimeZone(ZoneInfo.java:589)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.java:560)
    at java.util.TimeZone.setDefaultZone(TimeZone.java:666)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getDefaultRef(TimeZone.java:636)
    at java.util.TimeZone.getDefault(TimeZone.java:625)
    at java.util.Calendar.getInstance(Calendar.java:1613)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.ZipFileIndex$Entry.dosToJavaTime(ZipFileIndex.java:1103)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.ZipFileIndex$Entry.getLastModified(ZipFileIndex.java:1095)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.file.ZipFileIndexArchive$ZipFileIndexFileObject.getLastModified(ZipFileIndexArchive.java:191)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.preferredFileObject(ClassReader.java:2716)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.includeClassFile(ClassReader.java:2701)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.fillIn(ClassReader.java:2831)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.fillIn(ClassReader.java:2795)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.complete(ClassReader.java:2446)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.access$000(ClassReader.java:76)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader$1.complete(ClassReader.java:240)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:574)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.completeOwners(ClassReader.java:2458)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.complete(ClassReader.java:2435)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.access$000(ClassReader.java:76)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader$1.complete(ClassReader.java:240)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:574)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:1037)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.members(Symbol.java:978)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMethod(Resolve.java:1705)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findMethod(Resolve.java:1677)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve$9.doLookup(Resolve.java:2436)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve$BasicLookupHelper.lookup(Resolve.java:3097)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.lookupMethod(Resolve.java:3348)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.resolveQualifiedMethod(Resolve.java:2433)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.resolveQualifiedMethod(Resolve.java:2427)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.selectSym(Attr.java:3396)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:3278)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1897)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitApply(Attr.java:1825)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodInvocation.accept(JCTree.java:1465)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribExpr(Attr.java:625)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitExec(Attr.java:1593)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCExpressionStatement.accept(JCTree.java:1296)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:645)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStats(Attr.java:661)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBlock(Attr.java:1124)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:909)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:645)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitForeachLoop(Attr.java:1189)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCEnhancedForLoop.accept(JCTree.java:1035)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:645)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStats(Attr.java:661)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitBlock(Attr.java:1124)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCBlock.accept(JCTree.java:909)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:645)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitMethodDef(Attr.java:1013)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:778)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:576)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribStat(Attr.java:645)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClassBody(Attr.java:4364)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:4272)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:4201)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attrib(Attr.java:4176)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.attribute(JavaCompiler.java:1248)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile2(JavaCompiler.java:901)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:860)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:381)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:370)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:361)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:74)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.run(JavacTool.java:237)
    at net.testobjekt.ModuleGenerator.compileFile(ModuleGenerator.java:92)
    at net.testobjekt.ModuleGenerator.compileFiles(ModuleGenerator.java:73)
    at net.testobjekt.Algorithms.createModule(Algorithms.java:25)
    at net.testobjekt.configurator.Boot.proceed(Boot.java:129)
    at net.testobjekt.configurator.Boot.<init>(Boot.java:54)
    at net.testobjekt.configurator.Boot.main(Boot.java:17)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\lib\tzdb.dat (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(ZoneInfoFile.java:255)
    ... 82 more
```

PS sorry about this Cluster of text can't Format this

Comment: Maybe you have to check your classpath.

Comment: Add you source code, which you trying to compile.

Comment: please read [ask]

Comment: Do you have permission to read that file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that java is unable to find `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\lib\tzdb.dat`, which is a data file with time-zone data. Your installation of Java might be corrupted.

You should try out Oracle's timezone tool [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/tzupdater-download-513681.html) to fix the file.

(Documentation for the timezone tool is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html))

Comment: I just rediscovered this... What a crappy question. 
Nevertheless: You were correct. My java installation was corrupted!