# Getting java.io.streamcorruptedexception when run in linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, maven, exception

I'm getting following exception when try to run my java application in linux. java application was compiled and built in windows intellij using maven. openJDK 19 is used in both windows and linux. This is run in windows without any issue.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: File format not recognised
        at java.base/sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(ZoneInfoFile.java:270)
        at java.base/sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(ZoneInfoFile.java:260)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
        at java.base/sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.loadTZDB(ZoneInfoFile.java:260)
        at java.base/sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.<clinit>(ZoneInfoFile.java:255)
        at java.base/sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getTimeZone(ZoneInfo.java:589)
        at java.base/java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.java:585)
        at java.base/java.util.TimeZone.setDefaultZone(TimeZone.java:690)
        at java.base/java.util.TimeZone.getDefaultRef(TimeZone.java:661)
        at java.base/java.util.TimeZone.getDefault(TimeZone.java:650)
        at java.base/java.time.ZoneId.systemDefault(ZoneId.java:274)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryFileHeader.decodeMsDosFormatDateTime(CentralDirectoryFileHeader.java:165)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.CentralDirectoryFileHeader.getTime(CentralDirectoryFileHeader.java:148)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarEntry.<init>(JarEntry.java:59)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries.getEntry(JarFileEntries.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries$EntryIterator.next(JarFileEntries.java:410)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFileEntries$EntryIterator.next(JarFileEntries.java:385)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive$AbstractIterator.poll(JarFileArchive.java:233)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive$AbstractIterator.<init>(JarFileArchive.java:216)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive$NestedArchiveIterator.<init>(JarFileArchive.java:268)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.getNestedArchives(JarFileArchive.java:96)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.ExecutableArchiveLauncher.getClassPathArchivesIterator(ExecutableArchiveLauncher.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:55)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: File format not recognised
        at java.base/sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.load(ZoneInfoFile.java:304)
        at java.base/sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile$1.run(ZoneInfoFile.java:267)
        ... 23 more
```

Result for command: java -XshowSettings:properties -version
Property settings:

```
 file.encoding = UTF-8
    file.separator = /
    java.class.path =
    java.class.version = 63.0
    java.home = /ibl/dev/swe/appsrv/jboss-eap-6.4/jdk-19.0.1
    java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
    java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib
        /usr/lib64
        /lib64
        /lib
        /usr/lib
    java.runtime.name = OpenJDK Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 19.0.1+10-21
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 19
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = https://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 19.0.1
    java.version.date = 2022-10-18
    java.vm.compressedOopsMode = Zero based
    java.vm.info = mixed mode, sharing
    java.vm.name = OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 19
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 19.0.1+10-21
    jdk.debug = release
    line.separator = \n
    native.encoding = UTF-8
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Linux
    os.version = 2.6.32-754.50.1.el6.x86_64
    path.separator = :
    stderr.encoding = UTF-8
    stdout.encoding = UTF-8
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.library.path = /ibl/dev/swe/appsrv/jboss-eap-6.4/jdk-19.0.1/lib
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = UTF-8
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    user.country = US
    user.dir = /ibl/dev/swe/appsrv/jboss-eap-6.4
    user.home = /home/swe_d_jboss
    user.language = en
    user.name = swe_d_jboss

openjdk version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I tried to find an answer but didn't see similar kind of questions. I want to run my java application in linux server.

Comment: Not sure what's actually causing that but I'd compile the source on Linux as a quick (potential) solution

Comment: Without the code it's impossible to even guess..

Comment: @g00se I want to compile it in windows and run in any platform. Java should support it right?

Comment: *Should* yes, but I'm taking a guess it's not so much the OS here that's the problem as a subtle variation in the binary format of your timezone database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so much research I found a solution. I didn't want to compile the code in linux. Since java is cross platform supported it should run in linux.
The error said something is wrong with 'java.base/sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile'. According to the following I copied windows jdk tzdb.dat file into linux jdk. That solved the issue. now my jar is running in linux. Perhaps tzdb.dat in linux jdk is corrupted. I have no idea about that.
[How to fix tzdb.dat not found error in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55476716/how-to-fix-tzdb-dat-not-found-error-in-java)
[Compiler Error java.Lang.Error file not found exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39394450/compiler-error-java-lang-error-file-not-found-exception)